# How can we get the table row size in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, data-migration

Is there any way we can get the Cassandra table row size?
I'm planning to migrate Cassandra to DynamoDB. Since DynamoDB has a size limitation of 400kb I wanted to check the row size in Cassandra

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is not a row based system but it's column based. Therefore as long as none of your columns overflow 2 gigabyte you're not going to have any issues with Cassandra.

As far as I know there is no maximum size on Cassandra rows but rather a maximum size on Cassandra Columns. The limit is 2 gigabyte per column as mentioned here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data in order to get the size of a particular row.

Depending on your data model, you can estimate the size of the data using the statistics from the `nodetool tablestats` output which includes:

- minimum partition size (in bytes)
- maximum partition size (in bytes)
- mean partition size (in bytes)

But knowing the size of a row in Cassandra isn't really useful because a Cassandra row isn't the direct equivalent of a DynamoDB item -- it depends on how you have modeled the data in Cassandra and how you plan to model the data in Dynamo DB. Cheers!